3D plot - fill under curves
I have seasonal cycles per year from a time-serie.
library(rgl)

# example data
Month <- rep(1:12, times = 7)
Year <- rep(1998:2004, each = 12, times = 1)
Sat <- rnorm(84)
df <- data.frame(Month, Year, Sat)
df

rgl::plot3d(df, type = "l", xlim = c(0, 1.5), ylim = c(1998,2004), ylab = "Year", col = "blue")
sapply(2:7, function(i) plot3d(df, add = TRUE,type = "l", col = "blue"))
grid3d(c("x", "y+", "z"))
grid3d(side, at = NULL, col = "gray", lwd = 1, lty = 1, n = 2)
aspect3d(2,5,1)

Note that in this example, I haves lines between data curves that are not supposed to be here. I don't know how to fix this example. These strange straight lines doesn't appear with my real data.
I'm trying to have a kind of ridgeline plot like this:

I want to fill space under curves with a color. I tried geom_density_ridges but it doesn't fit with my data, since I don't want a density plot. I have three variables (Year, Month and Sat) to appear.
How can I do that?
